# Zooming without triggering OnClick function - Android

Tags: android, onclick, zooming

I have a picture where I will be able to zoom and unzoom the picture. 
This function below allows me to pop up (left/right) arrows when i click on the picture. 
However, when I zoom in or zoom out, it also trigger that function. 
What should I do to not detect the zooming instead just the click.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {



            if(prePage.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE &&       
nextPage.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            {
                prePage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nextPage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            else if(prePage.getVisibility()==View.GONE && 
nextPage.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
            {
                prePage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                nextPage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can perform the list item click programatically as well using

`mListView.setSelection(position);`
 it will call this function automatically you need not to do any click

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But from my code, I actually placed that in a galleryview function. I placed it in my main function and it works already.